# Loop out a string in to sub menu by placing tags within tags little example <li><ul>folder1<li><ul>folder2<ul></li><ul></li>

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am having a hard time trying to figure this out I would appreciate any help!.

I want to loop out a string in to its own sub menu by placing tags within tags little example

```
$string = 'foler1/folder2/folder3/folder4/';

$array = explode('/', substr_replace($string, '', -1));

foreach($array as $each_array){ // do something echo "<li>
<span>$each_array</span>
<ul>
//add new sub
</ul>
</li>";}
```

I want this output

```
//I would like to loop out this html code with each name
<li>
<span>folder1</span>
<ul>

<li>
<span>folder2</span>
<ul>

<li>
<span>folder3</span>
<ul>

<li>
<span>folder4</span>
<ul>

</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</li>
```

I managed to figure out what I need

```
  foreach($array as $each_array){ 
$list .= "<li>
    <span>$each_array</span>
    <ul>";}

  foreach($array as $each_array){ 
$list .= "</ul></li>";}

echo $list;
```

Comment: your expected output is invalid html. you might want to rethink that.

Comment: this is only a small aspect of the html that i am writing i just want my output with php, html is not a problem this will be placed in a valid html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an efficient answer but it works

```
<?php
$string = 'foler1/folder2/folder3/folder4/';

$array = explode('/', substr_replace($string, '', -1));

for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    if($i<count($array)-1)
    {
        echo '<li><span>'.$array[$i].'</span><ul>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<li><span>'.$array[$i].'</span>';
    }
}
for ($i=0;$i<count($array)-1;$i++)
{
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: yes thanks that is great, i managed to figure out how to do it, i appreciate your help

Comment: @user3115767 Don't forget to accept my answer (if and only if it works).